# How to use events and observers in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to track the Magento shop data by hooks the Magento events. I'm new in Magento2 so I don't know to hook the events and where to call an observer. I want to know how to call events which directory can we called. what hierarchy can be used? How to know the name of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a event file: events.xml**

**File**: *app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/etc/frontend/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
        <observer name="observername" instance="Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Observer\ObserverClass" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Create Observer class**

**File**: *app/code/Vendor_Name/Module_Name/Observer/ObserverClass.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor_Name\Module_Name\Observer;

class ObserverClass implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //Your code to run when event is fired.
        return 'Event fired';
    }
}
```

In above example, whenever event "*checkout_cart_add_product_complete*" is fired, the code inside Observer class will be executed.

To get a list of events available in Magento 2, you can visit : [Link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html#list-all-events-in-magento-2)

Thanks, I hope this will help you. If you have any doubt or problem, feel free to ask in comment.

Comment: I want to know the details of controller_action_postdispatch events like controller Name, action name,module name, route name and all the details related to that event. I have created an events.xml file where I called the event name then try to get the details from the observer. My question is how to get the details on that event? I have found to get the detail from $request like $this->_request->getControllerModule(); but I couldn't use \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request in observer. please Help

Comment: Please refer to this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69540/magento2-how-to-getrequest , if you've further more questions other than this one, please make an another question with all details and accept + vote if it help your current question.

Answer (score 0):

Very basic information about the events and observers you can find in the manual, check here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: I don't want to make custom events, I just need to hook the Magento events like frontend post-dispatch event, checkout event, confirm page event, login and logout event etc. Afterwards, I need to insert that data into the database table.

Comment: To hook events you need your observer. How to create observer you can read in the url to manual I pasted. And you need read that to understand how the flow between event and observer works. Magento events aren't different from the custom event you can create by your own. The thing is to use correct event name that magento dispatched in your `events.xml` file. Look, here you have list of all magento events https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html#list-all-events-in-magento-2 with the params.